# Clickable Toast with infinite duration on broadcast receiver possible?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, toast

I have to create an overlay view on top of Phone Application. When receiving call, I want to show some message to user and users can click the message or wait until the call end to dismiss this overlay view.

The stardard `Toast` works just fine here in case of only showing a message for specific time `LENGTH_SHORT` or `LENGTH_LONG`

But the problems occur here how can I register my button or view to `onClickListener`. and how can I make it infinite?

finally I start thinking about Can we possibly create background `Activity` not just `Service`? in this case it will solve everything.(I hope)

Thanks for all your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Toast system isn't designed to handle this kind of requirement.  You can't hook up an event listener, because the Toast isn't executed in your process, but rather passed to the foreground process and executed there. I'd suggest creating an Activity with a transparent background and popping up a Dialog in it.  Your BroadcastListener can then start that Activity  whenever it needs to (you'll need to be careful about which flags you specify).

Comment: transparant background block all the click to the Phone application but if we do the other way every view will be behind Phone application except from Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library: [SuperToasts](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts). I think there is everything you need.